# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel not working (3.1.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to get a simple carousel to work from Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1. I've stripped it down to the simple generic Bootstrap mark-up with no styling but I've still had no luck getting the images to slide. Would appreciate any suggestions. My mark-up is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      .container{
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- carousel -->
      <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/sample1.svg" alt="" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="images/sample2.svg" alt="" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="images/sample3.svg" alt="" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- .carousel-inner -->
      <!--  next and previous controls here
            href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- .carousel -->
      <!-- end carousel -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

    <!-- Javascript-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery plugins compiled and minified -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 4000
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure the javascript code is all loaded correctly? You are pointing to js/bootstrap.min.js which is a relative path. Is your js directory on the same level as the page you are running this from?

Comment: Thanks – yes, I've redirected it to be: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you're not pointing to a CDN version of bootstrap.min.js.

I say this because you're referencing jquery and the css from CDN locations but you're looking for the bootstrap.min.js to be local to your site.  Is this how you have it configured?

Change it to use

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8vvqf/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you open the html file directly, instead of from a server. Then the CDN url will become
`file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js`

change
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
to
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and try again?